# oracle query - how to equal from datetime and to datetime?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am struggling to solve this problem in a query. I need both datetime (from and to) with the same date to get result with the same date(different time dont matter). How to solve that problem? Hope you can help me with this. I know it is a small thing but i spent the whole day working on it. Dont understand what is problem. Thanks!

**oracle query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM person p
   INNER JOIN person_log pl ON p.ID = pl.person_id
   INNER JOIN address ad ON ad.id = pl.vendor_id
WHERE LOWER(ad.city) = LOWER (:cityname)
and pl.work_time >= to_date('2014-04-12 11:30:06', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')    
and pl.work_time >= to_date('2014-04-12 11:30:06', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

**Should be result:**

```
Person | WorkTime 
Piet   | 2014/04/12 11:22:06,757037 PM
John   | 2014/04/12 11:25:08,954737 PM
```

**My problem:**

The result: different date

Comment: Your two dates conditions are identical, is that really what you have?

Comment: Sorry you are right. I just update the post. Two dates should be the same but different time is fine.

Comment: I don't understand. If you use `>=` for both, then on is useless and you should remove it.

Comment: you mean second date >= should be removed?

Comment: Think about it for a while. Your query is asking e.g. worktime is greater than last week, and work time is greater than yesterday. Is the first test usefull at all? (Right now it's asking greater than yesterday and greater than yesterday, which makes even less sense)

Comment: Apart from the useless duplicated condition, the expected result can never match your example query. The value `2014-04-12 11:22:06` (from the "should be" output) is **before** `2014-04-12 11:30:06` (the value from your query). But your condition in the query compares using "after" (`>=`), therefor your query will never return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just enclose all dates in a TRUNC function if you are not bothered with the time as you say.

```
and TRUNC(pl.work_time) >= TRUNC(to_date('2014-04-12 11:22:06', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))    
and TRUNC(pl.work_time) <= TRUNC(to_date('2014-04-12 11:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
```

or depending on your situation

```
 and TRUNC(pl.work_time) <= TRUNC(:your_date_parameter)
```

Beware though, if you have an index on the work_time column then you will need to create a new index (function-based) as follows

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON person_log (TRUNC(work_time))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get data which belongs in the interval you must use

```
and pl.work_time >= to_date('2014-04-12 11:22:06', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')    
and pl.work_time <= to_date('2014-04-12 11:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
__________________^
```